# How to fix ERR_SSL_UNRECOGNIZED_NAME_ALERT in IIS

Tags: javascript, iis

After login page while loading the index.html page I am getting ERR_SSL_UNRECOGNIZED_NAME_ALERT error. Page app.js should load via http but the same is loading using https. Iam  using IIS 8.5 please suggest

Answer (score 0):

Check the Netscaler configuration as in this case there is issue with Netscaler. Netscaler which is defined on top of this site has not allowed app.js to load the same has affected this site to load